# Current user set to null even though is logged in

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created Auth Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { User } from 'firebase';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user: User;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      }
    });
  }

  async register(email: string, password: string, displayName: string) {
    await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    await this.user.updateProfile({ displayName });

    this.user.sendEmailVerification();

    return this.user.uid;
  }
```

after user is successfully registered i can access user property and call updateProfile function.

But i want to use this service also for updating profile information like: email or phone,
but whenever i do that i am getting user set to null.

Comment: Where do you get exaclty null?

Comment: when i use this user object outside of the register function

Answer (score 0):

That's because `user` at first is `null`. You might want to change your constructor as follows:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = localStorage.getItem('user'); // <-- Added this line
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      }
    });
  }
```

### You might want to read it:

I'm assuming you're getting null when you're trying to read from `AuthService.user`. This is expected.

`AuthService.user` at first is null, and after a successful response from firebase, you set `user` as `FirebaseUser` object.

In a different place, you're trying to fetch `user`. But the problem is that you're fetching it too soon. Meaning, you're fetching `user` when it's still null (because firebase hasn't returned any value yet).

In order to fix it, you need to set your `user` as Observable:

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user$ = new Observable(localStorage.getItem('user')).pipe(
      switchMap((fromLocal) => this.afAuth.authState),
      tap((user) => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)))
    );
  }
```

in a different class:

```
  authService.user$.subscribe(user => /** user: User **/); // Don't forget to unsubscribe
```

or in an HTML template (note the `async` pipe):

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="authService.user$ | async as user">
    <!-- user: User -->
  </ng-container>
```

and in your register, change to:

```
  async register(email: string, password: string, displayName: string) {
    await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    return this.user$.pipe(
      first(),
      tap((user) => user.updateProfile({ displayName }),
      tap((user) => user.sendEmailVerification()),
      map((user) => user.uid)
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

PS:

It's conventional to add `$` suffix for observables instances (e.g `user -> user$`).

Comment: i added this as you suggested and now when i called this.user.updateProfile({ displayName }); i am getting "this.user.updateProfile is not a function" error